# Installing Node with NVM on MacOS Ventura?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, nvm, macos-ventura

[I followed these steps](https://collabnix.com/how-to-install-and-configure-nvm-on-mac-os/) to install Node and NPM with NVM on MacOS Ventura and it worked fine.

If I try to rerun the install it tells me this:

```
oleersoy@Oles-MacBook-Pro fs-developer-md % nvm install node
v19.8.1 is already installed.
Now using node v19.8.1 (npm v9.5.1)
```

However if I open a new terminal neither the `npm` nor the `node` commands are available.

How do we make them available to all terminal windows?  The last time I did this install it was automatic ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add these line to your `~/.zshrc`.

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

And then restart your terminal or type below command in you terminal.

```bash
source $HOME/.zshrc
```

And do not follow any random guide, always go to official [docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Comment: Why you put backslash in front of the dot ? You can just do `. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`

Comment: You are right, actually we can remove both backslash and dot as well, I pasted it there because it was like this in the official docs.

Comment: On my M1, it was better following the NVM git repo docs. Using the commands there completed the process of install and configuring in one execution. I tried using Homebrew and manually added the configs to .zprofile, but the Terminal still did not recognize nvm command.